# Why are the mistaken civilian deaths in the Afghanistan war by the US army considered by some to be war crimes?

Tags: united-states, afghanistan, armed-conflict, war-crime

Isn't a war crime deliberate with malicious intent?
Shouldn't it be considered instead as blunders and bad decisions?

Specifically, I watched the leaked video of the helicopter /drone gunner shooting the civilians / children that he decided looked like terrorists, which Wikileaks released in 2007/2010. It seems that the Gunner is gung-ho trigger-happy, but not necessarily does he have malicious intent.

Comment: Some people think they are "deliberate with malicious intent" and not "mistaken". And I'm not sure your definition is accurate, (civilian) negligence can be (civilian) criminal

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Caleth It appears the relevant standard is/might be "gross or culpable negligence" in the case of US military justice https://www.court-martial-ucmj.com/files/2017/06/Targeting-and-the-Law-of-War-Admin-Investigation-and-Crim-Law-Supplement-30MAY17-Final-Approved.pdf

Comment: It would help if you added more detail to your Q. At this point it reads like a vague rant (possibly against a strawman), even if that was not your intention. Also, in emotionally charged cases random "some" can well use incorrect terms; we can't speak to their motivations at this level of generality. Even less random "some" can give their more informed opinions in such manner though, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_State_shootings#Legal_action

Comment: There are [serious angles/answers](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docs/v2_cou_gb_rule156) to a part of your Q (how much intent is actually needed in IHL for war crime), but the way you asked it precludes getting to those more substantive issues.

Comment: @origimbo: yeah, article 119 of UCMJ (on manslaughter) is listed under "law of war violation" in that text. More on that https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-wp0/wp-content/uploads/sites/78/2018/06/07014136/8.-MeierHill_Final-Review_Formatted.pdf

Comment: It seems like this Q. as currently phrased is less about Afghanistan in particular, than it is about War Crimes in general.

Comment: @agc technically yes

Comment: @Community edited. Please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two words, reckless endangerment.

This means deaths that are caused through carelessness or overzealous actions. This covers things such as not properly checking your targets, firing into a crowded area, or using heavier than necessary weapons that risk collateral damage.

For example laying down reactive fire with a .50 caliber against a building containing civilians. Or calling in a drone strike on a fleeing vehicle without determining whether the occupants represent a threat.

There have also been issues with training, such as issuing instructions in the wrong dialect, and then interpreting non compliance as a threat.

War crimes are typically viewed through the lenses of hindsight.

There have also been claims that accident civilian deaths have been covered up.

Comment: Is "rechless endangerment" a term in US law or in the international laws of war? I would have expected terms like "proportionality" and "military necessity."

Comment: @o.m. turns out it is in UCMJ (art. 114) but from the other sources mentioned under the Q it's not grouped under "law of war violation[s]".